# Quotient Groups and Subgroup Index

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

This might be a dumb question, but it will help with a homework problem:

Since the index of $H$ in $G$ ( or [$G$ : $H$] ) is the number of cosets of $H$, and $G$/$H$ denotes the group that contains all the cosets of H, then is [$G$ : $H$] = |$G$/$H$| (order) ?

Comment: Yes, but note that $G/H$ is a group iff $H$ is normal.

Comment: Yes I know that Just forgot to include that in my description. Thank you.

Comment: So $[G:H]$ is the number of cosets of $H$, and $G/H$ is the collection of cosets of $H$. So yes, $[G:H]=|G/H|$ *by definition*.

Comment: If you write it as $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$, there is no need to assume $H$ is a normal subgroup (of course this only works if $|G|$ is *finite*).

Comment: No, but $H$ must be normal in order for the quotient group $G$/$H$ to be defined.